# Checking GPG signatures in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gnupg

There is already [a solution](http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/) for extracting public keys and encrypting messages in JavaScript, but I cannot figure out how to decrypt messages or check signatures. Any ideas?

From what I can see, there is already a function for actually decrypting the message, now it's just a matter of extracting a private key so messages can be signed. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like step 1 is to decrypt the secret key string, then get the MPI (multi-precision integer), then separate it into the prime numbers and decryptor, which can be passed to the decryption function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a generic GPG/PGP NPAPI library for use in the browser that has public methods for most everything, including decryption and verification.

The plugin source is located here: https://github.com/kylehuff/webpg-npapi

The plugin is currently in use in the WebPG extension for chrome, located here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hhaopbphlojhnmbomffjcbnllcenbnih

And the extensions source is locate here: https://github.com/kylehuff/webpg-chrome

Both are cross-platform for Windows, Linux and OSX.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pinhikmcljjkhnpjmpfkhjgiaacajajm though I'm not sure if it works on Windows yet -- I'm trying it out myself right now.

Comment: It uses a plugin and works, but it is only for authenticating to websites with GPG, not signing messages or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, I also got it to work w/help from the developer. Idea: that extension may already have all needed functions and great GPG integration, so you'd only need to add an API to enable encrypting/decrypting messages. The developer is friendly, and I'd be happy to help testing and perhaps bugfixing to get message (de/en)cryption working. Source: https://github.com/gpgauth